# Как спарсить нужное значение с помощью jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

Есть div блок с информацией о человеке:

```html
<div class="content-columns">
 <div class="info">
  <span>Id:</span>
  <span class="details">3741</span>
 </div>
 <div class="info">
  <span>Gender:</span>
  <span class="details">Female</span>
 </div>
 <div class="info">
  <span>Birthday:</span>
  <span class="details">2001-02-17</span>
 </div>
 <div class="info">
  <span>Country:</span>
  <span class="details">United States</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Данные на страницах разняться у кого-то больше, а у кого-то только страна указана.
Сейчас выбираю таких образом:

```
String gender = peopleInfo.select("span:contains(Gender)").first().parent().children().get(1).text();
```

И получаю: `Female`, но данный код меня смущает, есть ли вариант более короче/красивее ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Соберите всю информацию из элемента `div class="content-columns"`:

```
Map<String, String> infoMap = document.getElementsByClass("info").stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(element -> element.getElementsByTag("span").first().ownText(),
                        element -> element.getElementsByClass("details").first().ownText()));
```

А потом делайте с ней всё, что нужно.

Comment: Спасибо, помогли, что то сам не догнал :(